# Why are my query results displaying differently when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This is strange... I'm displaying results in an HTML table but I'm getting a different number of results being displayed depending on if/how I am debugging. If I debug slowly and hit each line then all of the results show. If I just run it or don't step through each line then I only get one result in the table. Either way the result set does have the correct number of rows, they just aren't being displayed in the table correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas why this strange behavior is happening? I'm using Eclipse Indigo. Below is the block of code that I'm using to select the records and display them.

```
      try {
     String query =
     "Select * from plants where name = '"
     + name + "'";
     String plantName = "";
     ResultSet rs = sttmnt.executeQuery(query);

 while (rs.next()) { // display information for each plant.
        plantName = rs.getString(2);  // display fields in cells
        out.println("<tr><td>");
        out.println(plantName + "</td><td>");
        out.println(rs.getString(3) + "</td><td>");
        out.println("$" + rs.getString(5) + "</td><td>");
        out.println(rs.getString(4) + "</td>");
        out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"plantName" +
         plantNo + "\" value=\"" + plantName + "\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"plantID" +
         plantNo + "\" value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">");
        out.println("</tr>");
        plantNo++;
     }
     if (plantNo == 0) out.println("<tr><td align=\"center\" " +
          " colspan=\"4\">Sorry, there are currently no " + name
          + " plants for sale.</td></tr>");
     else
         out.println("<tr><td align=\"center\" " +
                 " colspan=\"4\">Showing " + plantNo
                 + " results. </td></tr>");

     out.println("</table>");
     rs.close();
  }
```

Comment: Looks good to me, try a file output stream

Comment: Not that its germane to the question, but you're opening yourself up to SQL Injection attacks with concatenated SQL.  Use bind variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending all the output to a `StringBuffer` and print that all out in one fell swoop. You'll save on objects, too. Your code becomes:

```
try {
 String query = "Select * from plants where name = ?";
 sttmnt.setString(1, name);
 String plantName = "";
 ResultSet rs = sttmnt.executeQuery(query);

 StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(); 
 while (rs.next()) { // display information for each plant.
    plantName = rs.getString(2);  // display fields in cells
    output.append("<tr><td>");
    output.append(plantName + "</td><td>");
    output.append(rs.getString(3) + "</td><td>");
    output.append("$" + rs.getString(5) + "</td><td>");
    output.append(rs.getString(4) + "</td>");
    output.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"plantName" +
     plantNo + "\" value=\"" + plantName + "\">");
    output.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"plantID" +
     plantNo + "\" value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">");
    output.append("</tr>");
    plantNo++;
 }
 if (plantNo == 0) output.append("<tr><td align=\"center\" " +
      " colspan=\"4\">Sorry, there are currently no " + name
      + " plants for sale.</td></tr>");
 else
     output.append("<tr><td align=\"center\" " +
             " colspan=\"4\">Showing " + plantNo
             + " results. </td></tr>");

 output.append("</table>");
 out.println(output.toString());
 rs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an `out.flush()` at the end of your code. It's likely that the data is just sitting in a buffer waiting to be sent when you run the code normally.